# Как в Bash изменить файлы во всех подкаталогах?

Tags: bash, sed

Добрый день необходимо изменить файлы для каждого пользователя на linux

пробывал вот такой вариант скрипта

```
sed -i 's:WallPaper=Fly-Default:WallPaper=/etc/image.jpg:' /home/*/.fly/theme/default.themerc
sed -i 's:WallPaper=Fly-Default:WallPaper=/etc/image.jpg:' /home/*/.fly/theme/current.themerc
```

Но файлы не изменились. Как еще можно перебрать папки?

Comment: воспользуйтесь утилитой find, сначала добейтесь что бы она искала и показывала именно те файлы, которые вы собираетесь менять. после этого добавьте ей параметр `-exec` так, что бы она выполняла sed (имя файла из find передается параметром `{}`)

Comment: а что выводят команды `ls /home/*/.fly/theme/{current,default}.themerc | wc -l`, `grep 'WallPaper=Fly-Default' /home/*/.fly/theme/{current,default}.themerc | wc -l` и `touch /home/*/.fly/theme/{current,default}.themerc` ? допишите в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было описано в комментариях, командой

```
find /home/ -type f -regex 'default.themerc\|current.themerc' -exec sed -i '|WallPaper=|s|Fly-Default|/etc/image.jpg|g' {} \;
```

`-type f` - выбираем только файлы

`-regex` - используется для выбора нескольких имен, если имя одно правильнее использовать ключ `-name`

выбираем файлы подходящие под условия и через `-exec` передаем их в обработку `sed`

Как и было описано в комментариях, подобные команды лучше сначала собирать без exec и убедится что выводятся именно те файлы, которые нужны.